# Задержка в kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Пишу на Python 3.7.4 
установил kivy но даже простая программа такая как:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='test')

TestApp().run()
```

работает с задержкой 5-7 секунд подскажите как исправить?

Comment: Что значит с задержкой 5-7 сек? Время загрузки? Или на нажатия так долго откликается?

Comment: например есть простая программа с одной кнопкой так вот клик срабатывает после 5-7 секунд так же с кнопками свернуть и закрыть

Comment: Выбросите свой компьютер! У меня такое было, когда я ставил Kivy на процессор power-pc 2005 года.

Comment: Xyanight Спасибо ваш ответ натолкнула меня на мысль что в моем ноуте есть интел hd и nvidia 920 я установил интел hd для экономии заряда батареи возможно если переключи на nvidia будет лучше

Answer (score 2):

переключение 
видеокарты сработало :)